# How do you code a cross join in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I have a process in my application that returns two different lists of objects.  The objects in both lists are of the same type.  I need to cross join the two lists together to form one integrated list.  If it were SQL, it'd be something like this:

```
SELECT A.KEY, A.DATA AS DATA1, B.DATA AS DATA2
FROM TABLE1 AS A
CROSS JOIN TABLE2
```

This is pure LINQ as the data is returned in actual generic List<> collections.

What is the LINQ syntax for this operation?

Tony

Comment: A cross join?  Why do you have an `ON` clause there?  Did you recently change from an inner join?

Comment: Upon some more research, I've found that my syntax is incorrect.  And it appears that I was wrong, I don't need a cross join.  Maybe it's an outer join that I need.  I need to get back 1 row where the keys in the two tables are the same.

Comment: @TonyVitabile, even if you've discovered that you actually need another type of join, can I suggest that you remove the `ON` clause? That would help future readers not get confused about your question and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res = from t1 in table1
          from t2 in table2
          select new
          {
              KEY = t1.KEY,
              DATA1 = t1.DATA,
              DATA2 = t2.DATA,
          };
```

Comment: You should add the equivalent of `A.KEY = B.KEY`.